# Hogan.js partials in pre-compiled template

Tags: javascript, node.js, hogan.js

Is it possible to have partials within a compiled template? It would appear like it's possible, as the partial name is referenced in the compiled object, but I have no idea how to get it to work.

I'm pre-compiling Hogan.js templates on the server side (node.js) and making them available on the client side. Here's a snippet of the template:

```
<ul class="log-{{id}}">
  {{#entries}}
    {{> entry}}
  {{/entries}}
</ul>
```

Once that template is compiled, I see a partials attribute in the object with a key of `<entry0`

I'm able to render the template on the client side using the following:

```
var data = {id: 11, entries: [{ id: 1, name: 'Entry 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Entry 2'}]};

template = new Hogan.Template(compiledTemplate);
template.render(data);
```

The template renders just fine, but nothing within the `{{#entries}} {{/entries}}` block. The partial itself is also pre-compiled and available on the client side. I've tried to pass that in several different ways, including:

```
 template.render(data, {partials: { entry: compiledEntryTemplate }});
```

All signs seem to point like this should be possible, but I just can't figure it out or find documentation anywhere that points out how to do it. I'm using Hogan.js 3.0.1

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If yes, providing answers will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figured it out. The following will make the compiled partial accessible in your compiled template.

```
 template.render(data, { entry: new Hogan.Template(compiledEntryTemplate) });
```

Comment: I have the same (or similar) issue as described in your question but I wasn't able to solve it with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

@TJ you can take a look at hogan.js test suite (https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/blob/master/test/index.js). There you'll find out a test case called "Partial Basic" which reads

```
  var partialText = "this is text from the partial--the magic number {{foo}} is from a variable";
  var p = Hogan.compile(partialText);

  var text = "This template contains a partial ({{>testPartial}})."
  var t = Hogan.compile(text);

  var s = t.render({foo: 42}, {testPartial: p});
  is(s, "This template contains a partial (this is text from the partial--the magic number 42 is from a variable).", "partials work");
```